# error in make: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: g++

I have a problem in makeing gpgpu-sim package in my Ubuntu. This is a ubuntu error and I do not know how to solve it

in the make file I have this

```
        g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libcudart.so \

        build/3010/release/libcuda/*.o \
        build/3010/release/cuda-sim/*.o \
        build/3010/release/cuda-sim/decuda_pred_table/*.o \
        build/3010/release/gpgpu-sim/*.o \
        build/3010/release/intersim/*.o \
        build/3010/release/*.o -lm -lz -lGL -pthread \
        /home/alireza/gpgpu-sim/v3.x/src/gpuwattch//obj_opt/*.o \
        -o lib/3010/release/libcudart.so
```

but I get the following error

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`

`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

`make: *** [lib/3010/release/libcudart.so] Error 1`

do you know how to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following commands should solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
sudo apt-get install freeglut3
```